# Producing double-slit interference in string theory

Tags: string-theory, double-slit-experiment, research-level

My full question is

**What brane configuration most economically reproduces a double-slit interference effect?**

It was inspired by [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/376771/string-theory-on-double-slit-experiment), which asks whether string theory has anything to say about the double-slit experiment. Well, we haven't identified a specific string vacuum as being the one that describes real-world electrons and photons; and string theory is just another quantum theory anyway, so one expects any differences between a stringy description of the double slit, and the description in QM or QFT, to be purely technical.

Nonetheless, although string theory contains e.g. all the phenomena of QFT, there is always some fine print, some extra detail added by the string-theoretic implementation; and you can't find out what those details are, without actually constructing it.

So I am interested in seeing stringy implementations of the double-slit effect. I envisage some sort of static brane configuration, that plays the role of apparatus, and then strings or small branes playing the role of diffracted particle...

Comment: Indeed the original question was far from trivial, as this question. Even though QM is the low energy limit of string theory, there are many interpretational issues open, and maybe a more fundamental theory could solve those.

Answer (score 1):

A paper today claims that ["String is a double slit"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.10951). The claim seems to be that the scattering of strings inherently includes interference effects similar to those in a double-slit experiment, via the different ways that strings can divide and recombine.